# Ajax making too many requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

So, I have made my code where it's supposed to send the data to the page `getData.php` whenever the user stops typing in the field `.search` for 3 seconds (considering that their done typing).  But I've noticed if say a user type slower (like 1 letter per second), or starts typing after about 1s it sends a whole bunch more Ajax requests for each letter typed (around 15 / 20 depending on how many letters). Rather than 1 request for the whole word.

This is my code:

```
$(".search").on('input', function() {
    $(".search").keyup(function() {
        timer = setTimeout(function() {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "getData.php",
                data: {search: $(".search").val()}
            }).done(function(data) {
                $(".searchReturn").text(data);
                $(".loading").hide();
            });

            $(".searchReturn").fadeIn(750);

        }, 3000);

        $(".search").keydown(function() {
            clearTimeout(timer);
        });

        $(".loading").fadeIn(250);
    });

    $(".searchReturn").hide()
});
```

---

`EDIT FOR BETTER UNDERSTANDING`

Say I typed "test" in the field, then I typed "test" again 1s and then having "testtest". When I had done this I got 55 Ajax POST's. I'm asking is, how do I stop this from happening.

Comment: You have event handlers inside event handlers, and the wrapping `oninput` event handler fires on every input and it keeps piling on event handlers up the wazzoo.

Comment: This is how it should be done -> http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/9Z78C/

Comment: @adeneo Yes, thank you, I've found a lot of errors, but I've fixed the, to suit my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add clearTimeout(timer); in keyup handler

```
$(".search").on('input', function() {
    $(".search").keyup(function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(function() {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "getData.php",
                data: {search: $(".search").val()}
            }).done(function(data) {
                $(".searchReturn").text(data);
                $(".loading").hide();
            });

            $(".searchReturn").fadeIn(750);

        }, 3000);


        $(".loading").fadeIn(250);
    });

    $(".searchReturn").hide();
});
```

Comment: I thought of that myself, but I'm curious why you think there are multiple keyup responses with an intervening keydown?

Comment: Try to add console.log to each handler and check that say called each one by one (  no duplicates ) - maybe something wrong in order of calling functions

Comment: This is wrong, the `keyup` handler is **inside** the `input` event handler, and that's the real issue.

Comment: Thanks, you're a life saver! Simple fix too.

Comment: @andeneo , All remove that `input` event handler as well.